# How to access Java Interface in kotlin fun?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to access java interface in kotlin class.
How can i do that?

```
public interface InterfaceCallback {
    void onComplete(Boolean isComplete);
}

public class Utils {

    //constructor
    public Utils() {}

    public void getCallbackEvent(Context context, String videoLink, InterfaceCallback interfaceCallback) {
        //...
        interfaceCallback.onComplete(true);
    }
}
```

I try to access this method in kotlin class as below but it's generate an error.

```
Utils().getCallbackEvent(this, videoLink) {it->
    Log.e(TAG, "getCallbackEvent: $it")
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface com.example.demo.InterfaceCallback implemented by class com.example.demo.activitys.DownloadScreen$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1 is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.example.demo.activitys.DownloadScreen$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1' appears in /data/data/com.example.demo/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes9.dex)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have to implement that interface somewhere.

For Kotlin:

```
class InterfaceCallbackImpl : InterfaceCallback {
    override fun onComplete() {
       // Implementation of the method
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to use InterfaceCallbackImpl